# How to conduct object detection again in bouding boxes after object detection?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolov5

For example, I want to use YoloV5 to detect intestinal cells first and get green boudingbox, and then detect intestinal bulges in green boundingbox.
I want to import boundingboxes from the first yoloV5 model into the second YoloV5 model, but how do I get boundingboxes into the second YoloV5 model？

Or you have other good ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would train a new Yolov5 model on both classes. By doing so you would only need a single inference to get the results.

If that is not possible I would input the clean image into the different models. Gather the bboxes of the different models and finally plot them on the original image. This is so that the previous bboxes do not impact the inference process negatively as the models has most certainly never seen bounding boxes during training.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved this problem, I used Yolov5 twice.

Comment: Consider marking my answer as such if it was helpful :) @Paul_Dx